# php win shell_exec with administrative user

Tags: php, windows, shell-exec

Is it possible to run shell_exec from php running under IIS using an administrative user instead of IIS_IUSR?
I have to call a java application from command line, but it acuses file permission issues when called from shell_exec(). The same command works fine when called from cmd.

```
java -cp "C:\Edi7\Itau\Edi7WebCli\bin\Edi7WebCli.jar" webclicfg.Edi7WebCli.Main -cXXXXXXX -p008 -tP
```